# current week if date() function and date from mysqli

Tags: php, date, mysqli, strtotime

I have a table containing the following:

```
StartWeek  | StartName |
2012-07-16 | 1         |
```

What I want to do. Is take the starting week, the current date, and calculate how much time has passed between then and now.

So far I have this:

```
function getCurrentWeekName() {
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    }
    else {
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        echo "Current date: ".$current_date = date('Y-m-j')."<br>";
        $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT StartWeek FROM Week");
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($start_date);
        while ($query->fetch()){
            $start_date = $start_date;
        }
        echo "start date: ".$start_date."<br>";
        echo "time passed: ".$time_passed = strtotime($current_date) - strtotime($start_date)."<br>";
        echo "number of days since start: ".$num_of_days = ceil($time_passed/(86400*7))."<br>";
        $week_num = ceil($num_of_days/7);
        $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT StartName FROM Week");
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($start_name);
        while ($query->fetch()){
            echo "Start name: ".$start_name = $start_name."<br>";
        }
        $week_num = $start_name + $week_num;
        echo "Week Number: ".$week_num;
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

The problem is, this returns the following information:

```
Current date: 2013-03-18
start date: 2012-07-16
time passed: -1342394787
number of days since start: -2219
Start name: 1
Week Number: -316
```

So clearly I'm doing it wrong. I think it must be something to do with my time passed calculation, maybe I shouldn't be using strtotime. Can anybody help?

Comment: Quite odd - it would be interesting to see the output of `strtotime($current_date)` and `strtotime($start_date)` separately because something seems wrong there.

Comment: Interestingly:
strtotime current_date: 
strtotime start_date: 1342396800

So nothing appears for current_date after strtotime, probably because it was created with date()?

Comment: @david: nope. it's just a string once it comes out of date. I get `21168000` as the diff when I do the strtotime() here with your sample dates above. One big flaw: you're calculating weeks in your `$num_of_days` (there's a `/7` in there), then you divide by 7 again in your week calculations. Doing the datediff in mysql gives me 245 days, which is 35 weeks.

Comment: Damn...I'm a bit stuck with how to implement the answer you provided. I get an error (as there's no FROM argument maybe?). I'm definitely messing it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for just a difference in days, you can do it [directly in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(now(), StartDate) AS diff_in_days
```

for other differences, e.g. hours, you can also do things like

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(now()) - unix_timestamp(start_date) AS seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The former query allowed me to reach the 245 days I needed. I would just divide by 7 then to get the weeks from there. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with php date-diff => http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Check if this you can use:

```
//replace the values for $startDate and $endDate:
$startDate = strtotime($startDate); 
$endDate = strtotime($endDate); 
$intervalo = date_diff(date_create($startDate), date_create($endDate));
$out = $intervalo->format("Years:%Y,Months:%M,Days:%d,Hours:%H,Minutes:%i,Seconds:%s");
    if(!$out_in_array)
        return $out;
    $a_out = array();

   array_walk(explode(',',$out),
    function($val,$key) use(&$a_out){
        $v=explode(':',$val);
        $a_out[$v[0]] = $v[1];
    });
    print_r($a_out);
```